# Eclipse Neon (4.6.3) Tomcat debug server menu is disabled

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

I am attempting to move a legacy java application that has been running under Jetty over to Tomcat 8.  To this end I want to launch the java app in a Tomcat 8 debug configuration from Eclipse so I can work through all the problems in the code and configuration.  However, when I open the Tomcat section of the Debug Configurations and add a new configuration the server menu is disabled and greyed out.

[Image of Tomcat Debug Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh5f9.png)

I have created and recreated the Tomcat server in the Server Configuration panel of Window/Preferences multiple times but the server select remains disabled in the Debug Configurations.

[Tomcat 8 server configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1acH5.png)

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would instead define and control Tomcat instances from the **Servers View**. The Launch Configuration dialog can't present the necessary UI for controlling the aspects of a server handled in configuration files, nor control which set of projects you're trying to include as apps on that server instance.